# @PathVariable is not working with non latin language

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect, seo

I have a controller method that gets a Post from the database.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/post/{id}", "/post/{id}/{title}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and the post table looks like this in the database:

- id
- title
- description
- slug

when I receive a GET request to get a post from the database, I fetch the post from database and check if the title slug in the URL matches the slug in the database, if they are the same I will display it and if not, I will redirect the request to the same method with the slug from database.

I tried the following code

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/post/{id}", "/post/{id}/{title}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPost(@PathVariable("id") Long id, 
        @PathVariable("title") Optional<String> title,
        Model model,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    Optional<PostDTO> postDTO = postService.findOne(id);
    if(postDTO.isPresent()) {
        String slug = postDTO.get().getSlug();

        model.addAttribute("post", postDTO.get());

        if( (title.isPresent() && !slug.equals(title.get())) || !title.isPresent()) {
            // redirect
            return "redirect:/post/" + postDTO.get().getId() + "/" + slug;
        } else {
            return "post/index";
        }
    } else {
        return "post/not_found";
    }
}
```

but when it reaches the redirect statement the id is sent, but the title is null, so I'm getting an infinite loop.

What did I do wrong?

UPDATE:

after some debugging, I found that my code is working fine if the text stored in the slug variable was English, but if it was Arabic it will be null.

```
return "redirect:/post/" + postDTO.get().getId() + "/" + slug;

return "redirect:/post/" + postDTO.get().getId() + "/" + "Hello"; // working fine
return "redirect:/post/" + postDTO.get().getId() + "/" + "مرحبا"; // not working
```

not working means that the `@PathVariable("title") Optional<String> title` will be null after redirection.

Comment: Just to clarify: 1) You're not using the **title** on the redirect, is that on purpose? 2) Could you add the cUrl that you're trying?

Comment: yes, I want the slug from db, not the title from the request,
the cUrl: curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/post/100/pretty-title'

Comment: I found the issue, it's about language @Villat

Comment: Could you try with another charset? For instance something like: `new String(title.getBytes(CharSets.ISO_8859_1));`